# Is there any way to update self.xxx in side_effect on MagicMock?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I want to test following oauth session class which update `self.xxx` attribute in their method.

`TestSample1` mock specified method only and it works.
But, IMO, this method is too complex if use multiple attributes and methods.

I want to `MagicMock` to handle multiple attributes and methods without assign.
I've wrote `TestSample2` and It's failed.

Is there any idea to improve `TestSample1` or `TestSample2`?

````
import unittest
from unittest import mock


# ----  Main code  ----
class OAuthSession():
    def refresh_access_token(self):
        # Some request for external API here.
        self.access_token = 'refreshed new token'


def target_method(auth):
    # Some check based on auth to refresh access token
    if auth.a.b.c.d.e:
        auth.refresh_access_token()
    return auth.access_token


# ----  Test code  ----
def mocked_refresh_access_token(self):
    self.access_token = 'mocked refreshed token'


# Passed. but setup conditions are complex
class TestSample1(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('test_sample.OAuthSession.refresh_access_token', autospec=True, side_effect=mocked_refresh_access_token)
    def test_target_method(self, _):
        oauth_session = OAuthSession()
        oauth_session.a = mock.MagicMock()
        oauth_session.a.b.c.d.e = True
        oauth_session.g = mock.MagicMock()
        oauth_session.g.h.i.j.k = True

        result = target_method(oauth_session)
        assert result == 'mocked refreshed token'


# Failed. I want to write like this.
class TestSample2(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('test_sample.OAuthSession')
    def test_target_method(self, _):
        oauth_session = OAuthSession()
        oauth_session.a.b.c.d.e = True
        oauth_session.g.h.i.j.k = True
        oauth_session.refresh_access_token.side_effect = mocked_refresh_access_token

        result = target_method(oauth_session)
        assert result == 'mocked refreshed token'


# Failed. I want to write like this also.
class TestSample3(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_target_method(self):
        oauth_session = mock.MagicMock()
        oauth_session.a.b.c.d.e = True
        oauth_session.g.h.i.j.k = True
        oauth_session.refresh_access_token.side_effect = mocked_refresh_access_token

        result = target_method(oauth_session)
        assert result == 'mocked refreshed token'```
````

#### Errors

```
ERROR: test_target_method (test_sample.TestSample3)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sheile/test_sample.py", line 59, in test_target_method
    result = target_method(oauth_session)
  File "/home/sheile/test_sample.py", line 15, in target_method
    auth.refresh_access_token()
  File "/home/sheile/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py", line 1081, in __call__
    return self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sheile/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py", line 1085, in _mock_call
    return self._execute_mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sheile/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py", line 1146, in _execute_mock_call
    result = effect(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: mocked_refresh_access_token() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: The function to test has 3 features and none of them actually requires an `OAuthSession` to test. You seem to mock much more than you need to mocked.

Comment: I want to test `target_code`. This method check condition on `OAuthSession`, will call `refresh_access_token` on `OAuthSession` and return `access_token` on `OAuthSession`.

If I'm not mistaken, these 3 features require `OAuthSession` and need mocking to test `target_method`.

Comment: No, they need a mock that can handle these three things.

Comment: Okay. I've changed the code in question.